# Why does getPrototypeOf aways return Object {}

Tags: javascript, prototype

Consider this snippet:

```
var organism = Object.create(null);
var mammal = Object.create(organism);
var cat = Object.create(mammal);
var Garfield = Object.create(cat)

Object.getPrototypeOf(Garfield) => Object {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(cat) => Object {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(mammal) => Object {}
```

I thought x = Object.create(y) will set the prototype of x to be y.  And yet, it looks like the prototype of every object I created is Object {}.

What's up with that?

Comment: You... started with a blank object... and then kept prototyping it... it has always been a blank object....

Answer (score 0):

If you think of objects as just associative arrays, then it makes sense that since all you did was create new objects from an initially empty object, that they all have the same prototype-- that of the empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct `x = Object.create(y)` will set the prototype of x to be y.

```
var organism = Object.create(null);
var mammal = Object.create(organism);
var cat = Object.create(mammal);
var Garfield = Object.create(cat)

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Garfield) === cat);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(cat) === mammal);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(mammal) === organism);
```

I usually only use Object.create to set prototype of constructor functions instead of creating instances: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941